# XmlDocumentFragment equivalent in LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, documentfragment

I am unable to find something like `XDocumentFragment`. Is there an equivalent of `XmlDocumentFragment` in LINQ to XML?

I know that I can keep nodes in a collection. But how to conveniently serialize a bunch of various nodes to string, like this:

```
new XDocumentFragment(myNodes).ToString()
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to achieve? Pretend that `XDocumentFragment` *did* exist, and show us how you'd use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply concatenate string representation of nodes:

```
var xml = String.Concat(myNodes);
```